# Spark Batch reading from Kafka failed when payload is Null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a Spark batch pipeline reading data from Kafka with a custom deserializer.

```
 val deviceRdd = KafkaUtils
      .createRDD[String, Option[Activity]](spark.sparkContext, kafkaParams, offsetRanges, PreferConsistent)
      .flatMap(_.value())
```

Custom deserializer (deserialize into a protobuff generated class)

```
  override def deserialize(topic: String, data: Array[Byte]): Option[Activity] = {
    Activity.validate(data) match {
      case Success(value) => Some(value)
      case Failure(exp) => None
    }
  }
```

However, this pipeline failed with a `NullPointerException` when the payload from Kafka is `null`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.Option$.option2Iterable(Option.scala:21)
    at com.app.job.SparkJob$.$anonfun$apply$2(SparkJob.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:511)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
```

`(SparkJob.scala:56)` refers to the `flatMap(_.value())`.

This is the `null` kafka message extracted using kafkacat

```
{"topic":"activities","partition":15,"offset":524009012779,"tstype":"logappend","ts":1654940098134,"key":null,"payload":null}
```

How should I configure the Spark jobs to ignore or log occurrences of `null` messages from Kafka?

Comment: Hmm. I didn't think Kafka record key **and** value could be null, but why not filter before the flatMap?

Comment: The messages producer service also stated similarly that their code wouldn't ever set `null` to key or message. Yet that's what I'm facing.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use Structured Streaming? Then filter nulls out of the dataframe's byte columns, and *then* deserialize using a UDF?

Comment: Unfortunately, that would be a massive refactoring on our part.

Comment: Okay, so how about `.createRDD[String, Array[Byte]]`, then `filter` that, then flatMap (or just map since you no longer should need an `Option` if the filter can remove all invalid data)?

Comment: Strangely the pipeline works when the value I use `.createRDD[String, Array[Byte]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think the deserializer is the issue, invoke it manually after you've filtered bad data

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[ByteArrayDeserializer],
```

```
val deviceRdd = KafkaUtils
      .createRDD[String, Array[Byte]](spark.sparkContext, kafkaParams, offsetRanges, PreferConsistent)
      .filter(record => record.key() != null && record.value() != null) 
      .map(_.value())
      .map(v => deserialize(v))  // return Activity objects
```

I'd recommend using Structured Streaming rather than legacy streaming, though, or at the very least, use `toDF` method shortly after the above RDD is created